# Roslyn AdditionalFiles

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to develop a Roslyn Code Analyzer which has access to some static configuration in the form of text files. Since an analyzer cannot access the local file system I guess the only way to read such external configuration is via Context Option and AdditionalFiles.
I am aware of this example dealing with this problem:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Using%20Additional%20Files.md

What the example does not say is: Is the analyzer reading the AdditionalFiles shipped with the analyzer assembly or the target being analyzed? The latter does not solve my problem because the configuration is analyzer and not target specific.

**Update**:

I cannot use the standard "Add New Text File" resource mechanism either. The according context menu entry is disabled:

[image: AddNewTextDisabled]
[image: FreshAnalyzerProject]

This seems to be related to the TargetFrameworkProfile which is set to Profile7 when creating a new "Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)" project.

Comment: Why not make the config a embedded resource in your analizer and just access it that way?

Comment: Yes in theory a good idea but somehow the (default?) PCL profile 7 which seems to be the one used for Analyzers, does neither offer Type.Assembly nor something like Assembly.Current to access the resource. Maybe I'll find a way to do this here on SO.

Comment: It works with this code: http://expediteapps.com/blog/tip-reading-files-as-embedded-resources/
I can access the embedded text file directly in the running Analyzer then. This was your idea Scott. If you want to just copy that link or the basic idea into an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: I posted my own solution using a different way, if you want to post the solution you found too and accept it that is fine with me too.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers. I think they do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.resources.resourcemanager#System_Resources_ResourceManager__ctor_System_Type_) of the `ResourceManager` class and just pass in a type defined in your assembly.

```
class MyResourceManager
{
    private readonly ResourceManager _manager;

    public MyResourceManager()
    {
        _manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResourceManager))
    }

    public string GetStringResouce(string name)
    {
        return _manager.GetString(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: First try failed. am I missing anything here? "System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Analyzer1.MyResourceManager.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Analyzer1" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'" In the csproj I have "<ItemGroup><EmbeddedResource Include="TextFile1.txt" /></ItemGroup>" without any further resources file.

Comment: You need to add a .resources file (just right click add new item to project, it is in the template list) and link the TextFile inside of that file as a linked file

Comment: Oh and also, once you do that (assuming you made a `MyResourceName.resources` file) you will be able to do `MyResouceName.TextFile1` and have it return a string. No need to create a `ResourceManager` object at all.

Comment: I have edited the question with some screenshots. It seems like Profile7 does not allow adding (text) files to a resources file :/